# Is there any way to automatically paste text vertically into google sheets?

Tags: database, google-sheets

I have about 10 years worth of data from a local animal shelter and I need to copy all kittens under 3 months over from Excel spreadsheets onto a google sheet, their ID, age in days, month of intake, intake year, sex, and intake type . I am doing this for a research project, it has to just be the data points and nothing else. The aggregate [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnN20.png).

I look through the excel spreadsheets and type the relevant data onto notepad. All the data points I need are separated by date with all the kittens taken in on that date, with their age, sex and ID number corresponding to the order they're in so I can find discrepancies easily and input the data in quickly, it usually turns out looking like this:
(3/14) 74 M A25164093
(3/18) 34 27 34 M F M A25192748 A25192760 A25192795
(3/19) 70 F A25202463
(3/20) 80 2 1 1 F F F F A25208017 A25210624 A25210625 A25210626

My main bottleneck is putting it into the data aggregate. I have to go cell by cell inputting this data into the columns and I feel like there has to be a way to copy the data I need vertically onto the columns they belong in.

I've tried the transpose function and it seems to perfectly match what I need, however it requires the data points transposed vertically to already be somewhere on the google sheet, and if I try and delete the cell with the function so it's just the data it transposed it also deletes all the data it tranposed vertically. It seems to only function to display the data. This is not ideal, I need something that just copy and pastes data into the columns they belong in so that it can be useable.

This is an old sample of the data aggregate (output):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pUaU4ChFHwL9suqAGRUegBQ72F1-rusp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115130932279005924436&rtpof=true&sd=true

And this is a sample of the input:
(5/2) 10 10 10 M F F A27729208 A27729210 A27729212 (5/3) 26 30 26 30 9 9 9 9 2 9 9 M M F F M M M F F F F A27732515 A27732516 A27732518 A27732520 A27732521 A27732541 A27732542 A27732543 A27732545 A27732546 A27732547 A27732549 (5/4) 29 54 54 40 61 M M F M A27735990 A27735996 A27736005 A27740796 (5/4) 29 54 54 40 61 M M F M A27735990 A27735996 A27736005 A27740796 (5/6) 26 26 16 26 14 33 21 21 F F F F M M U U A27760967 A27760970 A27760973 A27760977 A27761539 A27761720 A27762164 A27762169 (5/7) 21 21 F M A27767085 A27767091 (5/8) 47 51 52 51 F F M M A27779894 A27782370 A27782371 A27782373 (5/9) 19 60 60 36 67 67 M F M F F F A27787353 A27788037 A27788043 A27788687 A27788911 A27788923 (5/11) 47 47 47 28 F M M M A27798156 A27798165 A27798168 A27801540 (5/12) 20 10 27 27 52 F M M M F A27810744 A27811484 A27812447 A27812449 A27818279 (5/14) 21 21 21 U U U A27829238 A27829239 A27829241

Comment: Please share a file containing a sample of the data and the expected output. It'll help folks help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your input looks. But if you need to paste transposed, you have a specific function in Sheets by copying and right-clicking:

[image]

Select "Transposed" and it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly for my purposes, thanks!